# trying to serve files first with fallback to cakephp with nginx using same route

Tags: file, nginx, cakephp, static

We are currently migrating from apache, and with nginx I have to be able to both serve files inside `api/webroot` and execute php scripts with CakePHP. For example, the route `/api/login` should be resolved by CakePHP, whereas `/api/picture/pic.png` should be served as static file.

I am trying to solve it by using fallbacks, but it seems like `try_files` doesn't resolve to the fallback `@cakephp`, instead returning a 404 error straight away.

My currently broken site configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/user/site;
    index index.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location /api {
        set $path "";
        if ( $request_uri ~* "^/api/(.*)$" ) {
            set $path $1;
        }
        try_files /api/webroot/$path /api/webroot/$path/ @cakephp;
    }

    location @cakephp {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/webroot/index.php?$args;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/webroot/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we solved it by adding restrictions to the route and matching it to a regex

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # listen 443 ssl;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl;

    root /home/user/site;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html;

    location ~* ^/api/(.*[^(php)])$ {
        add_header X-debug-message "$1" always;
        try_files /api/webroot/$1 @cakephp;
    }

    location @cakephp {
        add_header X-debug-message "$uri" always;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/webroot/index.php?$args;
    }

    location / {
        add_header X-debug-message "root" always;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index /api/webroot/index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        add_header X-uri "$uri" always;
    }
}
```